# How to make an object in box2d have constant velocity even after collision?

Tags: box2d, ios

I have iOS game where I have a bouncing character. Everything is being handled by box2d. The problem is when the character hits a wall of another character it's velocity changes, but I don't want this. I need the velocity to stay constant even after collisions.

I was thinking the only way to do this was to keep setting the velocity after each collision unless there's another way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I just need to know generally if there's an easy way to make it happen or not.

Comment: His velocity changes direction and speed or just direction?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, you want the velocity to stay the same when the character hits a wall? i.e you want the character to pass through walls?

Comment: @NauticalMile It is not a duplicate (I think), because the question you mentioned dealt with a flying body and this one with a bouncing body. In this first case I'd use a *kinematic* body if understood the question correctly and in this one I'd consider increasing the mass dramatically and then applying a tiny force to re-stabilize speed.

Comment: @Zehelvion ok I see now. Phil wants the _velocity_ to be maintained, not just the speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the velocity of a body (and have it ignore collisions), just set the body type using the [`b2body::setType`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/classb2_body.html#a34ff1c84b10b74eb990749a025a1b1ad) function:

```
mybody.setType(b2_kinematicBody);
```

Alternatively, the `b2BodyType` can be assigned to the `b2BodyDef` before the body is created using the [`b2BodyDef::type`](http://arme-mod.googlecode.com/hg-history/9d4908fceb62955903e08b586ff8fdf09ce10107/arm.mod/box2d.mod/Documentation/html/structb2_body_def.html#a89cc3ad1873908042b002147b3861381) public attribute:

```
mybodydef.type = b2_kinematicBody;
```

All kinematic bodies will move with constant velocity, completely ignoring collisions.